# Remove words from <div> generated on load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a webpage for a family member, and most content is generated upon load. 
My specific problem lies in a news-function, where you can add new products. Because of the way the website is built we have added a link to the news-item, in order to allow costumers to go directly to the product. ( link is "Se mere" )
Trouble is:
When adding the new item to the news-feed, all links and formatting disappears when its shown on the right side of the page. (This is where the code is from)
Therefore, i would like to remove the "Se mere" text from the right coloumn, in the div class = "NewsItemPreviewText"

Unfortunately, i cannot access that part of the code, so i cannot choose what and how its printet.

***Here you can see original code that i have access to,***

```
`<div id="RightColumn">{$Design.rightColumn}</div>`
```

***and this is how the code looks when generated.***

```
<div id="RightColumn">
<div id="pagenews-box">
<div id="pagenews-box-top">
    <h2>Nyheder</h2>
</div>
<div id="pagenews-box-content"> <div class="NewsItemPreview NewsItem1">
<div class="NewsItemPreviewImg">
    <a href="/nyheder/4-revitive-isorocker-/#4" title="Revitive Isorocker ">
    <img src="/upload_dir/news/REVITIVEIX.w50.h50.crop.jpg" style="border:0px;" alt="Revitive           
Isorocker ">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="NewsItemPreviewContent" style="width:110px">
<div class="NewsItemPreviewDate">
    <a href="/nyheder/4-revitive-isorocker-/#4" title="Revitive Isorocker "     
class="NewsItemPreviewLink">Revitive Isorocker </a>
    <br>
<div class="NewsItemPreviewDateCreated">26/11 2014 kl. 12:20
</div>
</div>
<div class="NewsItemPreviewText">
Årets julegavehit!
KUN 1795,-kr. hos os!&nbsp;

Se mere
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="pagenews-box-bottom">
</div>
</div>`
</div>
```

I hope you can help, please let me know if i have omitted any necessary details or code.

Comment: What platform are you using? The `{$Design.rightColumn}` is some type of template.

Comment: The platform i am not sure about, it is from a hosting-company, having specific design templates for this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery this can be done by targeting the container("NewsItemPreviewText") containing the text "Se mere" and removing it.

```
$('.NewsItemPreviewText:contains("Se mere")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("Se mere").join(""));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxvjyo29/)

Comment: Oops. Other similar answer was posted while I was typing, but this differs in that it will target just the container that you have identified as having the text "Se mere". Rather than removing all instances of "Se mere" anywhere.

Comment: Very good idea to add the container. Possibly faster and more precise.

Comment: If this did not work, make sure it inside a: $(document).ready(function() {});

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it with jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/wilchow/pzrn88m4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".NewsItemPreviewText").text($(".NewsItemPreviewText").text().replace("Se mere", "")); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

```
$(':contains("Se mere")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().split("Se mere").join(""));
});
```